# Wrong autogenerated package from notebook containing #key and Part as subscript

Tags: bugs, packages, associations, pure-function

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and persisting through 10.1.0 or later**

---

*Mathematica v10.1.0, under Windows 8.1 x64*

*Mathematica v10.0.2, under Windows*

1) Define a function **in an initialization cell**:

```
lowerBound = 
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(#Range\), \(\(\[LeftDoubleBracket]\)\(1\)\(\
\[RightDoubleBracket]\)\)]\) &;
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

2) Test the function (OK)

```
lowerBound@<|"Range" -> {1, 2}|>
```

> 1

3) Save this notebook (as test.nb) and choose to autogenerate the package with initialization cells.

4) Load the auto-generated package.

```
Get["test.m", Path -> {NotebookDirectory[]}]
```

5) Show the definition (ah!)

```
?? lowerBound
```

> lowerBound=Range[[1]]&

[image: Mathematica graphics]

6) Test the function (Error!)

```
lowerBound@<|"Range" -> {1, 2}|>
```

> During evaluation of In[5]:= Part::partd: Part specification
>   Range[[1]] is longer than depth of object. >>
>
> Range[[1]]

### Update: Wolfram Research Opinion

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for your email.
>
> I have filed a bug report with the
>   development team. Thank you very much for giving us feedback and
>   hopefully this issue would be improved in future release. For the time
>   being, you can use "#Range[[1]]&" for the function definition (note
>   that [[1]] is not a subscript of "#Range").
>
> I hope this helps and
>   please let me know if you have any other questions.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> Wolfram Technical Support

Comment: I can confirm the problem in 10.0.2 under Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the update from WRI.  I added the bugs tag and standard header.